# Google sheets last opened time stamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How do I see the exact time stamp a sheet was opened on Google Sheets? I can see the date it was opened under ‘Last opened by me’ but not the exact time (unless opened today). Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is such function in Google sheet

Comment: `viewedByMeTime` is available in Drive API using [Files.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?hl=en). However, you need to provide the file id to get the file information. If you are planning to open the file to get the file id then the viewed by me time will be updated accordingly. If you are open for a solution that will require you to use multiple procedures using Drive Api without opening the sheet to get its id, just let me know so I could provide a guide on how to do that

Comment: Thanks Ron.  I am open to looking at it yes.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that this solution will only provide you the `datetime` you last viewed the file. It will not show you the `datetime` when another user opened/viewed a Google Sheet file.

### Use [Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk?hl=en) (either API explorer or choose your preferred programming language):

- Use [Files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to search for files in your drive. Use the `query term` to filter your search.
- In this example query, I want to get all the files in my drive with Google Sheets `mimetype` having the file `name` of 'Copy of Inventory'

**Sample Request using API explorer:**

```
q: mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and name = 'Copy of Inventory' 

fields:files/name, files/id, files/viewedByMeTime
```

**Sample Response using API explorer:**

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1-zarWNraQWigfRl6YyjhUpWHEROVaR9BcAxxxxxx",
   "name": "Copy of Inventory",
   "viewedByMeTime": "2021-05-18T17:12:39.630Z"
  }
 ]
}
```

---

### You can also do this in Apps Script using [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) which uses [Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk).

> Note that the file name tag in Drive API v2 is `title`

**Sample Code:**

```
function getSheetViewTime() {
  var query = 'mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" and title = "Copy of Inventory"';
  Logger.log(query);
  var files = Drive.Files.list({q:query});
  Logger.log(files.items[0].lastViewedByMeDate)
}
```

**Result:**

```
5:53:14 AM  Notice  Execution started
5:53:16 AM  Info    mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" and title = "Copy of Inventory"
5:53:16 AM  Info    2021-05-18T17:12:39.630Z
5:53:16 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```